# Videos uploaded with facebook api are visible to me but not to others

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

Today i've uploaded some clips using Facebook video api and there is a problem.
The problem is that videos uploaded on my page are visible to me but not to other people. Not even the other admins can't see them. Now the obvious answer would be "the privacy".
But that's the thing, it's public. I don't know what i'm doing wrong

```
$attachment = array(
    'access_token' => $this->token,
    'name' => isset($story->name) ? $story->name : $story->title,
    'description' => $story->description,
    'source' => '@' . realpath($story->resource)
);
$result = $this->facebook->api($this->getUploadUrl($story->page, $story->type), 'post', $attachment);
```

It's all working fine. I'm not getting any errors. The result from this request would be somthing like

```
{"id":"693098840722877"}
```

Thank you!

Comment: Please answer your question an accept it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh dear God. The application was in "sandbox" mode. So that's why other people could not see the posts

Answer (score 1):

I think maybe you for got Privacy.

```
attachment = array(
    'access_token' => $this->token,
    'name' => isset($story->name) ? $story->name : $story->title,
    'description' => $story->description,
    'source' => '@' . realpath($story->resource),
    'privacy' => json_encode(array( 'value' => 'EVERYONE' ))
);
```

Comment: I've tried it right now and it's not working
[link](https://www.facebook.com/photo.php?v=693145694051525)

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else having the same problem, As Samuel Todosiciuc mentioned, check your App *live* status. I was going insane trying to figure out why public posts of programmatically uploaded videos were not showing for others.

I didn't find any *sandbox* setting per se, it was *putting it live*.
Go to your App page > App review > "Make (your app) public?" > put it to live.

Comment: Samuel Todosiciuc is the OP of the question ;)

Comment: Yeah, I realized that, should've phrased my post more aptly. Edited to reflect what I meant.